# Query database table using LIKE in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to query a table using where like :

```
Auth::user()
    ->friends
    ->where('friend.first_name','LIKE','%'.$firstName.'%')
    ->all()
```

The query does work properly without using the `LIKE` statement only when i add the `LIKE` keyword it doesn't return any results.

Comment: You need to better articulate your question, did it work before adding like? What happens when you use the column name only as the first parameter: ```Auth::user()->friends->where('first_name','LIKE','%'.$firstName.'%')->all()```. What database are you using?

Comment: We need more explanation to understand your main point of the question

Comment: the where query works without adding LIKE it returns the results but when i add LIKE in the query it dosen't return anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confused between a laravel relation and a eloquent collection. First let me go straight to answer, you would have to do

```php
Auth::user()
    ->friends()
    ->where('friend.first_name','LIKE','%'.$firstName.'%')
    ->get()
```

To explain what's wrong with your code, `->where('name', 'Like', '%something%')` This is a query builder method. You have to use it on the query builder, or **Before** you actually retrieve the model / model collection.

```php
Auth::user()->friends()
```

This would give you a relation `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany` that you can apply where like on.

---

```php
Auth::user()->friends
```

This will return you a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`. And yes, it is a collection, so you will have to use collection method. Take a look at the  [where method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-where) for collection. You can see it only support key => value pair. It does not support "LIKE"

> The where method filters the collection by a given key / value pair:

If you want to use achieve a "Like" on collection, you can probably use the [filter method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-filter), which support custom callback.

> The filter method filters the collection using the given callback, keeping only those items that pass a given truth test:

To conclude, when you define a `friends` "HasMany" relation on `User`, you have two way to retrieve it.

If you want to apply additional query builder method, you need to use `user->friends()` which do not return you data, it return you a relation that you can use query builder method. Once you do `user->friends`, it get you a collection. You cannot apply query builder on that anymore. So basically, `user->friends` is act the same way as `user->friends()->get()`

Answer (score 1):

Using `all()` will work without the builder `where()` statement.

When grabbing data using the query, use `get()` instead:

```
Auth::user()->friends->where('something','LIKE','%'.$something.'%')->get()
```

Comment: i replaced all() with get() i got this error : Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), 0 passed

Comment: I don't know what your relations are, so I don't know what's coming in.  If you have a collection already, then try without `->get()`.  IE see what happens with just the where statement - if you already have the DB pull for friends, the collection will return without the `->get()`.  But this is strange behavior.

Comment: Alternatively, you might be accessing friends as an **attribute** rather than a collection.  You can try to query the relationship (assuming you have this relationship actually setup correctly in your user model):
`Auth::user()->friends()->where('first_name','LIKE','%'.$firstName.'%')->get()`.  Note the `()` after `friends` in this test.

Answer (score 0):

Don't Use `all()` and use `get()`.

```
Auth::user()->friends()->where('something','LIKE','%'.$something.'%')->get()
```

Comment: i replaced all() with get() i got this error : Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), 0 passed